# Remover uma quantidade N de dias em uma data

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Como remover uma quantidade de N dias em uma data ?

```
namespace TesteData
{
  class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dataAtual = DateTime.Now.Date; // dataAtual 13/09/17
        var qtdDias = 5;

        //Como fazer essa dataAtual 13/09/17 - qtdDias = 08/09/17 ?
        //dataAtual = 08/09/17
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simplesmente:

```
namespace TesteData
{
  class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var qtdDias = 5;
        var dataAtual = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(qtdDias*-1); // dataAtual 13/09/17
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Não tem um método de subtração, mas é só usar um truque matemático com o método [`AddDays()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.adddays):

```
using System;
                    
namespace TesteData {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            var dataAtual = DateTime.Now.Date;
            var qtdDias = 5;
            var novaData = dataAtual.AddDays(-qtdDias);
            Console.WriteLine(novaData);
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando **ideone**](https://ideone.com/D781AC). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XKKTMf). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/SubtractDays.cs).

> To subtract a particular time interval from the current instance, call the method that adds that time interval to the current date, and supply a negative value as the method argument. For example, to subtract two months from the current date, call the `AddMonths(Int32)` method with a value of -2.

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.subtract?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).